# How to import javascript files in html with Flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, three.js

I have an Html page with a javascript part in which I include some other .js files :

```
<script type="module">

            import * as THREE from "../build/three.module.js";

            import { OrbitControls } from './jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
            import { STLExporter } from './jsm/exporters/STLExporter.js';
            import { STLLoader } from './jsm/loaders/STLLoader.js';
            import { GUI } from './jsm/libs/dat.gui.module.js';
            
            ...
```

It displays what I want when I open my html page in a browser.

The problem happens when I want to run this html page on my local server using Flask.

It doesn't work if I don't modify the imports :
[It doesn't find the files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXsZ6.png)
so I tried to create a static repository in which I put jsm repository and use url_for() like this :

```
<script type="module">

            import * as THREE from "../build/three.module.js";
            import { OrbitControls } from "{{ url_for('static',filename='jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js') }}";
            import { STLExporter } from "{{ url_for('static',filename='jsm/exporters/STLExporter.js') }}";
            import { STLLoader } from "{{ url_for('static',filename='jsm/loaders/STLLoader.js') }}";
            import { GUI } from "{{ url_for('static',filename='jsm/libs/dat.gui.module.js') }}";
```

It seems to work for static files : [It finds static files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcn8O.png)
Nevertheless, it doesnt work for three.module.js file which is in build repository.
 I even tried to put it in static repository or to use url_for() for this import...
But all I tried seems to not work.

Can someone have an idea about how I can import this module usefull for threejs ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Move the three.module.js in static/jsm folder and import it as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static',filename='js/three.module.js') }}"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, the build folder is at the same level as the static folder. But the problem seems not to be the path since I tried to put the entire path like D:/.../build/three.module.js and it does not work aswell.

Comment: Try moving it into the static directory and import it in the following way: `<script type="module" src="{{ url_for('static',filename='jsm/three.module.js') }}"></script>`

Comment: or if the browser return the error: _Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/plain"_, try with: `<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static',filename='js/three.module.js') }}"></script>`

Comment: I imported as u suggered : `<script type="module" src="{{ url_for('static',filename='three.module.js') }}"></script>` and it returns me this : `127.0.0.1 - - [28/May/2021 13:03:20] "GET /static/three.module.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -` on top of the response but it displays this too : `127.0.0.1 - - [28/May/2021 13:03:21] "GET /build/three.module.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -` but there is no other import

Comment: Are you sure there are no other imports? Because I've tried it with: `<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static',filename='js/three.module.js') }}"></script>` and it seems to import it correctly. You can also try to clear your browser cache.

Comment: Yes there is no other import, in my code when there is THREE.anything it seems to want to import from build/three.module.js

Comment: Have you tried creating a separate project just to try to see if you can successfully import the javascript module, and then integrate it into your main project? It would help you figure out where the problem might be.